# Hard Disk Re-Parition if Dell Recovery Disk

Tags: dell-xps

I purchased Dell XPS laptop. It comes up with 750GB Hard disk and Windows 7 Home Premium. After turning ON the laptop there was only **one Partition OS (C:)**.

I splited this partition into multiple partitions. After this i created Dell Recovery DVDs using **Dell DataSafe Local Backup**.

Now If I restore OS using this recovery Discs will it restore partition to one large Partition (Factory settings) or keep my existing partition's structure.??

I do not want to take risk by doing it my self. I have very important data on other partitions.

Did anyone knows what will happen if I restore OS using recovery Discs???

Answer (score 0):

All the installed softwares will restore as is.

**Note:** Beyond your restore point(That is, the point when you take the backup), whatever you installed it won't restore.

Using `Dell DataSafe Local Backup`, you need to take `full system backup` OR `(system files + important drive files)`

As far as I know, Logical drives may not be restored back (excluding **C:** drive).